# How to use "useUnwrap()" composable in nuxt-content?

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, nuxt-content

I was reading nuxt-content docs about [useUnwrap()](https://content.nuxtjs.org/api/composables/unwrap) composable. It says that the functionality is the same as [unwrap](https://content.nuxtjs.org/api/components/content-slot#props) prop in `<ContentSlot>` component. But the docs does not give any example about using this composable. For example if I have a component called `TestContent.vue` in `/components/content/TestContent.vue` directory with the code below:

```
<template>
  <div>
      <h2 class="fancy-header"><ContentSlot :use="$slots.default" ref="element"/></h2>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue'

const element = ref(null)

onMounted(() => {
  useUnwrap("p", element);
})

</script>
```

How could I use `useUnwrap` composable to unwrap **p** tags in this component? The code I wrote is **just** my try to understand that and does not work at all!

Comment: The official useUnwrap() documentation has been updated. Have you seen the latest changes?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I did not know how to use that and changing docs was a good news for me.